# Storing a remote path by name in Hg

Tags: mercurial

In git I can `git remote add x http://...` then `git pull x` how can I do this in hg?

I was told to add the following to `.hgrc`:

```
[paths]
x = http://...
```

so I added the above to `/path/to/repo/.hgrc` then tried `hg pull x` and got the following error:

```
abort: repository x not found!
```

where x was `mozilla` and `http://` was http://hg.mozilla.org/labs/jetpack-sdk/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hgrc file is in `/path/to/repo/.hg/hgrc` (note there's no period in front of the name).  It looks like you created a file called .hgrc in the root of the repository, which Mercurial doesn't recognize.

You could also do `hg clone http://hg.mozilla.org/labs/jetpack-sdk` which would create a local repository and pull all of its files in one step.